# PHP and wordpress

Tags: php, api-design

i am WordPress and php developer. i am working on the plugin development
for ethereum. i does't find the sdk or api for the php or
JavaScript. can you please guide me for the API documentation for the
ethereum.

Comment: web3 api based on javascript can be used to communicate with blockchain smart contracts. You can also use AJAX method to send data from javascript to php after invoking the contract method from web3.

Comment: What version of PHP are you programming in?

Answer (score 4):

Ethereum comes up with a javascript API called - Web3

Brief description -

> To make your app work on Ethereum, you can use the web3 object
>   provided by the web3.js library. Under the hood it communicates to a
>   local node through RPC calls. web3.js works with any Ethereum node,
>   which exposes an RPC layer.

Here is the link for your reference  - https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API

Comment: Is Ethereum is same as waveplatform or different?

Comment: Not sure about waveplatform but Ethereum is one of the popular blockchain implementations.

Comment: how to use  Ethereum for transfer bit coin?

Comment: How to get Ethereum API and where we get this API?And how to use this API in php or javascript?

Comment: I've shared the API documentation in my answer, please take a look at it for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You might combine JS fronted technology like [web3js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js) for user interaction and verify on [PHP-library](https://github.com/digitaldonkey/ethereum-php) level.

[image]

[Drupal Module](https://github.com/digitaldonkey/ethereum) and there is the [PHP-library](https://github.com/digitaldonkey/ethereum-php)